# OpenCV debugging

Tags: c++, opencv, static-libraries

I want to see how the function `findchessboardcorners` in `opencv` works internally and I see from the source in calibinit.cpp that there is some debug code that might help me with that if `#define DEBUG_CHESSBOARD` is uncommented.

The question is how do i actually do this with opencv being a lib? Just uncommenting the `#define DEBUG_CHESSBOARD` line does not work and i guess that is because the source was build into a static lib which i am using, or is this wrong? But do i then have to build the whole opencv lib again with this small change to actually run the debug code? 
Thanks

Comment: Will do this ``#define DEBUG_CHESSBOARD`` in your project file help?

Comment: Yes, you have to recompile the code, but it does not have to be into a library. I'd suggest keeping it seperate from the already compiled release code if you're going to mess around inside it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to built lib if the code is guarded under debug macro.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add calibinit.cpp to your project? Else try to do it, comment the include of precomp.h and do what you want with the code...

Answer (score 0):

I built my OpenCV from source, using cmake and then make.  If you edit the top-level CMakeLists.txt file, and add `add_definitions(-DDEBUG_CHESSBOARD)`, then rerun cmake, rerun make (and rerun "sudo make install" if applicable), this will turn this option on.